# What are upper reflectivity bounds of materials

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, material-science, reflection, wavelength

I know that if i take metal-coated fiber i can send light signals to large distance, because signal would reflect inside fiber, lowering attenuation. Just like in optical fiber communication network. But if i increase frequency then at some point it would turn to gamma ray and would dissipate through fiber. What is upper frequency boundary for different materials?

PS. This can be reworded as "What minimum wavelength (max frequency) can we use for carrier for guided communication line?"

Comment: In practice, a metallic coated fiber will have much more attenuation than the usual dielectric-guided kind, because of the finite conductivity of the metal. It will probably be essentially useless at optical wavelengths, never mind gamma rays.

Comment: @ThePhoton Okay, but for materials, in general - what is the best one for maximum frequency carrier, and what is that frequency? Question is theoretical, we can assume vacuum inside guided channel. the only important point is ability to do channel bends of same sane radius, eg >=2-5 meters